# Is there history of windows activity that is tracked within windows itself?

Tags: python

I want to write a script that helps employees in a small startup with the tracking of their working hours.

It's supposed to tell them when and how long they were active on the current machine.
For example, Last week: Monday: [Idle(0:00am - 11:59pm)] ; Tuesday [Idle(0:00am-8:00am), Active(8:01am-5:00pm), Idle(5:01pm - 11:59pm)] ; .... and so on.

1. Does Windows store this information somewhere?
2. If not, how complicated would it be to write a script that tracks this information?
   I'm not really a programmer. I've only written a few small scripts in Python to make some office work more convenient. Pretty much regarding tracking of working hours.
   I'm also a little afraid regarding the topic of privacy. I don't want to get any information that I'm not supposed to. If there would be some advice from people who worked on something similar, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just have them fill out timesheets like every other business? Tracking exactly how long their computers were active seems rather draconian (and it would also imply that meetings aren't considered work).

Comment: Depends what exactly you mean by 'active', but one very crude measure might be the system uptime which you can access via the `psutil` package according to [its documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Filling in timesheets is exactly what happens now. Employees are complaining, as this seems rather tedious to do and is a little time consuming (our working schedules are a little more complicated than usual). Like I said, the system I'm trying to deploy is 100% voluntary and only supposed to give the employees a "suggested timesheet" which they can just sign and forward to me. But thank you for your answer, the whole idea might become a little too political.

Comment: It may also be [more work than you expect](https://xkcd.com/1319/).

Comment: You might also consider looking at the dozens of available timesheet mobile apps.